# Magento Use of undefined constant tmp in core file

Tags: magento, zend-framework, caching, undefined, constants

My magento store is returning that error:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153`

But my line is:

`return new $backendClass($backendOptions);`

I cannot see what file is exactly the error. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere in your code you put `tmp` instead of `$tmp`. Run a search over all of your code for `tmp`.

Comment: Thank you, but my error was solved with `Mage::log` function, that have show me the full error log. By the way, thanks for the answer.